# Can JSTL tags be used as functions?

Tags: html, jsp, jstl

I'd really, really like to use c:out as an EL function to HTML-escape my output, like so:

```
<c:set var="myOutput" value="${ c:out(myRawData) }" />
```

Unfortunately, it barks at me:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/views/products/lineitem.jsp (line: 130, column: 1) The function out cannot be located with the specified prefix
```

Anybody know how to do this (or do HTML-escaping of output in EL another way?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `c:out` tag, there's no need to write a function.

```
<c:set var="myOutput"><c:out value="${myRawData}"/></c:set>
```